# Bazel builds defaulting to Visual C++ instead of mysy2 mingw64 (windows 11)

Tags: c++, windows, build, mingw, bazel

I am trying to build with Bazel and would like to force the build to use mingw gcc/g++ compiler, but Bazel defaults to using  Visual C++ to compile protobuf files though I do not have VC installed. I have followed various build instructions here and in official Bazel documentation.

Bazel throws the following errors:

```
bazel build --config=mingw_config -s //modules/common_msgs:all --verbose_failures

ERROR: C:/users/../_bazel_<>/adtmuovd/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:155:11: Compiling src/google/protobuf/generated_message_tctable_lite.cc [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): vc_installation_error_x64.bat failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target @com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_lite)
  cd /d C:/users/../_bazel_<>/adtmuovd/execroot/axiomatic
  SET INCLUDE=msvc_not_found
    SET PATH=msvc_not_found
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
    SET TEMP=msvc_not_found
    SET TMP=msvc_not_found
  external\local_config_cc\vc_installation_error_x64.bat @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt-exec-ST-e846b08c7501/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/_objs/protobuf_lite/generated_message_tctable_lite.obj.params
# Configuration: 6f64c59b653c8bf6154079f7422f26f2bd342280541403f67c9022aed5ba617e
# Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host
```

Below is my .bazelrc

```
# Use custom-configured MinGW c++ toolchain.
build:mingw_config --crosstool_top=//toolchain:mingw_suite

# Use --cpu as a differentiator.
build:mingw_config --cpu=x64_windows

# Use the default Bazel C++ toolchain to build the tools used during the build.
build:mingw_config --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain
```

Below, my toolchain BUILD file

```
load(":cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "cc_toolchain_config")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_toolchain_suite(
    name = "mingw_suite",
    toolchains = {
        "x64_windows": ":mingw_toolchain",
    },
)

filegroup(name = "empty")

cc_toolchain(
    name = "mingw_toolchain",
    all_files = ":empty",
    compiler_files = ":empty",
    dwp_files = ":empty",
    linker_files = ":empty",
    objcopy_files = ":empty",
    strip_files = ":empty",
    supports_param_files = 0,
    toolchain_config = ":mingw_toolchain_config",
    toolchain_identifier = "mingw-toolchain",
)

cc_toolchain_config(name = "mingw_toolchain_config")
```

and the cc_toolchain_config.bzl:

```
# NEW
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/cc:action_names.bzl", "ACTION_NAMES")
# NEW
load(
   "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_toolchain_config_lib.bzl",
   "feature",
   "flag_group",
   "flag_set",
   "tool_path",
)

all_link_actions = [ # NEW
   ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_executable,
   ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_dynamic_library,
   ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_nodeps_dynamic_library,
]

def _impl(ctx):
   tool_paths = [
       tool_path(
           name = "gcc",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++",
       ),
       tool_path(
           name = "ld",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ld",
       ),
       tool_path(
           name = "ar",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ar",
       ),
       tool_path(
           name = "cpp",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/cpp",
       ),
       tool_path(
           name = "gcov",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcov",
       ),
       tool_path(
           name = "nm",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/nm",
       ),
       tool_path(
           name = "objdump",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/objdump",
       ),
       tool_path(
           name = "strip",
           path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/strip",
       ),
   ]

   features = [ # NEW
       feature(
           name = "default_linker_flags",
           enabled = True,
           flag_sets = [
               flag_set(
                   actions = all_link_actions,
                   flag_groups = ([
                       flag_group(
                           flags = [
                               "-lstdc++",
                           ],
                       ),
                   ]),
               ),
           ],
       ),
   ]

   return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
       ctx = ctx,
       features = features, # NEW
       cxx_builtin_include_directories = [
           "C:/msys64/mingw64/include",
           "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
           "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed",
           "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include",
           "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0",
       ],
       toolchain_identifier = "local",
       host_system_name = "local",
       target_system_name = "local",
       target_cpu = "x64_windows",
       target_libc = "unknown",
       compiler = "gcc",
       abi_version = "unknown",
       abi_libc_version = "unknown",
       tool_paths = tool_paths,
   )

cc_toolchain_config = rule(
   implementation = _impl,
   attrs = {},
   provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

Apart from this, I have also tried the flags --compiler=mingw-gcc,
--incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution following https://bazel.build/configure/windows#using

```
platform(
    name = "x64_windows-mingw",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
        "@platforms//os:windows",
        "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:msys",
    ],
)

register_execution_platforms(
    ":x64_windows-mingw"
)

register_toolchains(
    "@local_config_cc//:msys_x64_mingw",
)
```

But, Bazel's auto configs tries to use Visual C++ and I am not where it is picking it from. I have checked my windows env variables and do have anything related VC set over there. Appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue.